# How to fix Jasper Layout

Tags: jasper-reports

[image: jasper report]

Hi, I have a issue with Jasper Layout. 
I have a table of varying sizes. I want the chart below to move automatically on the second page as the table changes. 
In my case the table invades the chart and this last does not move its position.
I choose as option of the chart frame and the chart itself position type = float and Stretch type = Container bottom. For the table position type = Fix Relative to Top and Stretch type = Element group Bottom. The table's frame position type = Float and Stretch type = Element group Bottom

Here below an extract of my xml source:

```
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="812" height="58" uuid="157a4d6c-6d63-4e88-bf88-5f6fd55a3631">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box padding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#F2FA19"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement x="5" y="1" width="414" height="18" forecolor="#000000" uuid="7c20b7c6-a42a-42ed-bcfb-9379ce3d8cf8">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Banca: " + $P{ATTR_DESC_ABI}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="5" y="15" width="678" height="12" forecolor="#000000" uuid="beb8584c-7db1-4c69-9f60-8da31d30b12c">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["ABI: " + $P{UID_ABI}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement x="5" y="27" width="678" height="12" forecolor="#000000" uuid="851f392d-e2bb-408a-8dcd-b9d1b624330d">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Periodo di riferimento: " + $P{ATTR_DESC_DATA_RIF}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="508" y="8" width="277" height="11" forecolor="#000000" uuid="b8d1d77f-26c9-47e6-bf1b-c0db35b0bf9b">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Justified">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[(*) Gli importi si riferiscono alle sole operazioni di prelievo contante da ATM]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement x="5" y="40" width="295" height="18" forecolor="#008F47" uuid="3777540a-b90a-495f-97ed-b217e956ed07">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Prelievi ATM (importi*)"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" x="0" y="70" width="812" height="210" uuid="8dfea57d-76eb-44ac-8157-5f798bc1881d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box padding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#202FFA"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" mode="Opaque" x="5" y="8" width="550" height="191" uuid="c2090e8b-603d-4376-af24-2c3037102531">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table 8_TH"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table 8_CH"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table 8_TD"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value=""/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="PRELIEVI_ATM" uuid="ad27e294-9ec8-4c54-b26b-e0cbfb96a2c2">
                            <datasetParameter name="UID_REPORT_Q1">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{UID_REPORT}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="ATTR_PATH_ROOT_Q1">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ATTR_PATH_ROOT}+"/themes/images/delta.png"]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:column width="90" uuid="5efe6b59-a1a9-4fef-92de-b93b7378402c">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 8_TD" height="14">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </box>
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType3" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="14" uuid="9abd44d2-0c74-4969-86ea-76f76740ce86"/>
                                    <box leftPadding="3">
                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_DESC_RIGA_01}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="90" uuid="2069d828-9abc-4ecd-a708-129b9ca16d04">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 8_TD" height="14">
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </box>
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType3" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="14" uuid="b010c0e0-4534-4322-b32a-18b51d496a25"/>
                                    <box leftPadding="3">
                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_DESC_RIGA_02}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="80" uuid="dccd07c5-d80f-4c56-a611-28c6ff0af797">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 8_TD" height="14">
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </box>
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="14" uuid="a2a94053-9adf-4d97-9a4e-a60f2065470b"/>
                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_MESE_01}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="80" uuid="20d29486-969a-4ed3-b5bb-ccf11402436f">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 8_TD" height="14">
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </box>
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="14" uuid="d5987a19-9c16-408d-b7d2-01fa3ae3deee"/>
                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_MESE_02}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="80" uuid="160934e6-5233-45bb-bca0-955f12d4653b">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column5"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 8_TD" height="14">
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </box>
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="14" uuid="6adb1a36-331c-4c0c-8d7d-12656c7317cd"/>
                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_MESE_03}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="130" uuid="80e8d1fc-4354-42a0-a0a4-e914141e7ad1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column6"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 8_TD" height="14">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </box>
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement key="" style="StyleRowType2" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="14" uuid="478b8e0e-d6c4-46c3-aa96-8484537c3737"/>
                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_CONFRONTO_MESE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                                <image>
                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="13" y="3" width="10" height="7" uuid="651496e9-c688-46c5-b2b2-92ab93386b5a">
                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{CODE_TIPO_RIGA}.equals( "HEADER" )]]></printWhenExpression>
                                    </reportElement>
                                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{ATTR_PATH_ROOT_Q1}]]></imageExpression>
                                </image>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                    </jr:table>
                </componentElement>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement x="590" y="8" width="220" height="191" uuid="819fc066-05d6-4ce7-9f7a-eb5067eecb89">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table 9_TH"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table 9_CH"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table 9_TD"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="PRELIEVI_ATM" uuid="b5d2c1ab-3db7-4018-90d1-69036b48e46d">
                            <datasetParameter name="UID_REPORT_Q1">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{UID_REPORT}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="ATTR_PATH_ROOT_Q1">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ATTR_PATH_ROOT}+"/themes/images/delta.png"]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:column width="90" uuid="ef78e814-4dfb-47c8-89f5-629d6b86dcbf">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 9_TD" height="14">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </box>
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="14" uuid="066f4604-06b8-498e-84eb-cc4ee5f214a8"/>
                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_MESE_ANNO_PREC}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                        <jr:column width="130" uuid="451b85b2-159e-4241-956c-ea9a2eebe911">
                            <jr:detailCell style="Table 9_TD" height="14">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </box>
                                <textField>
                                    <reportElement style="StyleRowType2" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="14" uuid="08facb80-1b7e-4b18-8490-f089564b5db6"/>
                                    <box rightPadding="3">
                                        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    </box>
                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VAL_CONFRONTO_ESERCIZIO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                                <image>
                                    <reportElement x="13" y="3" width="10" height="7" uuid="064efec4-b29a-4c1b-977e-b23ebc30cfb8">
                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA["HEADER".equals($F{CODE_TIPO_RIGA})]]></printWhenExpression>
                                    </reportElement>
                                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{ATTR_PATH_ROOT_Q1}]]></imageExpression>
                                </image>
                            </jr:detailCell>
                        </jr:column>
                    </jr:table>
                </componentElement>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" x="0" y="270" width="812" height="260" uuid="240ad497-3263-4262-b871-49e97d2de359">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#15ED39"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <bar3DChart>
                    <chart evaluationTime="Report" customizerClass="com.stonemob.jcu.customizer.CustomLegendList">
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="11" y="30" width="790" height="220" uuid="865bf597-06b6-4dc5-8f6a-1b3e22cb402e">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box padding="0">
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <chartTitle>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </chartTitle>
                        <chartSubtitle>
                            <font size="8"/>
                        </chartSubtitle>
                        <chartLegend>
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="6"/>
                        </chartLegend>
                    </chart>
                    <categoryDataset>
                        <dataset>
                            <datasetRun subDataset="PRELIEVI_ATM_CHART" uuid="a194edd8-4279-4307-b308-289509998e98">
                                <datasetParameter name="UID_REPORT_Q2">
                                    <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{UID_REPORT}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                </datasetParameter>
                            </datasetRun>
                        </dataset>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Visa"]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_DESC_FASCIA}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_VS_VAL_FASCIA}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Mastercard"]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_DESC_FASCIA}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTR_MC_VAL_FASCIA}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                    </categoryDataset>
                    <bar3DPlot isShowLabels="true">
                        <plot>
                            <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#008000"/>
                            <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#003D90"/>
                        </plot>
                        <itemLabel>
                            <font fontName="SansSerifDejaVu Sans" size="6"/>
                        </itemLabel>
                        <categoryAxisFormat>
                            <axisFormat labelColor="#003C8F" tickLabelColor="#000000" verticalTickLabels="false" axisLineColor="#000000">
                                <labelFont>
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="6"/>
                                </labelFont>
                                <tickLabelFont>
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="6"/>
                                </tickLabelFont>
                            </axisFormat>
                        </categoryAxisFormat>
                        <valueAxisFormat>
                            <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" verticalTickLabels="false" axisLineColor="#000000">
                                <labelFont>
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="6"/>
                                </labelFont>
                                <tickLabelFont>
                                    <font fontName="SansSerifDejaVu Sans" size="6"/>
                                </tickLabelFont>
                            </axisFormat>
                        </valueAxisFormat>
                    </bar3DPlot>
                </bar3DChart>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="57" width="13" height="134" forecolor="#000000" uuid="1dace233-882c-4f81-84b8-bd604a83357b">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Bottom" rotation="Left">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Prelievi ATM (importi)]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </frame>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the positions of the frames in your report so that they don't overlap.

The first frame has `y=20` and `height=58`, so it ends at `y=78`.

The second frame has `y=70` and `height=210`, ends at `y=280`. You should move it to `y=78` (or lower) so that it doesn't overlap the first frame.

The third frame has `y=270`.  Move it to `y=280` (or at `y=288` if you move the second frame to `y=78`) so that it doesn't overlap the second frame.

`positionType="Float"` is good, but I don't think you need `stretchType="ElementGroupBottom"` for the frames, it would be safer to reset the stretch type attribute.